# How to access webmail of old server(plesk) from another new server(cpenel)

Tags: cpanel, plesk

dns of domain abc.com was pointed to ns0.dns.com and ns1.dns.com
webmail.abc.com was pointed to hord.

Recently I moved abc.com website to new server, so I have update the dns record to ns1.newdns.com, ns2.newdns.com.

website is working fine, so are the emails(webmail) on new server.

Now Old emails are still on old server, which I don't want to move to new server, instead I want a way to access old server hord(webmail).

Now after dns is pointed to new server, webmail.abc.com is also pointed to new cpanel server which is right.

To access old server hord(webmail), I have added a A record on new server with webmailold.abc.com with older server ip.

once I access this, instead of opening old server webmail(hord), it shows plesk default page from old server.

Do I need to do any extra configuration on old dns records to attach hord to wemailold.abc.com?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then what you have done is, essentially, to rename the old webmail host name to `webmailold` in DNS, without making any changes to the old web server (just introduced the new one which you intend to use for everything else).

*Assuming* that you are using name-based virtual hosting on both servers (if you were using IP-based virtual hosting, which is awfully uncommon these days, this wouldn't be a problem), you need to either:

- use the same name as you used before and point that old name to the old server, *or*
- reconfigure the old server so that it recognizes the new name for the host as its own and serves the appropriate content

Either of these will bring the old web server and current DNS into sync. Once you have done either, you should be able to access webmail on the old server and have everything else on the new server.

If you don't have the level of control to be able to do either of the above, but you do have control over the clients' resolver settings, you could potentially set up a local resolver which will resolve the (old) webmail host name to the IP address of the old server, and forward everything else. That is a very different question, however.